# How to get types from dll of an ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, reflection

I have a `ReflectionMvc.dll` file of an ASP.NET Core MVC project. This project has a `HomeController` with a view `Index.cshtml`. I want to load the `.dll` file from another MVC project to view the `Index` page.

I have tried like this:

```
var fileName = "ReflectionMvc.dll";

if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    Console.WriteLine(fileName + " found!");

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(fileName);

    Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

    foreach(Type t in types)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fileName);
```

and

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(fileName));
```

I'm getting this error for my 2nd approach:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
> more of the requested types.
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm getting another error for my 3rd approach:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'ReflectionMvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=MSIL'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'ReflectionMvc,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=MSIL'
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyName,  ObjectHandleOnStack requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you want to do such a thing? from my knowledge, views are not compiled into your dll but your dll references your cshtml files. Saying that, using reflection to get types from a dll will not get you what you looking for. An alternative would be storing your views in a centralized server or storing them in blob storage, on startup create a directory and pull down the views, reference the views in the directory which you will store them in.